# Stacked histograms with ggridges package in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggridges

The following code produces histograms that overlap. How can I modify this code to make the histograms stack on top of each other?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggridges)

iris %>% 
      pivot_longer(cols = -Species,
                   names_to = "Param", 
                   values_to = "Value") %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = Value, y = Param))+
      geom_density_ridges(aes(fill = Species),
                          stat = "binline",
                          alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

I can achieve a desired effect using `geom_histogram` and `facet_wrap` as shown below, but from aesthetics perspective prefer a solution using `ggridges`.

```
iris %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Species,
               names_to = "Param", 
               values_to = "Value") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Value))+
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = Species),  
                 position = position_stack(), 
                 alpha = 0.5) +
  facet_wrap(~Param,ncol = 1,scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you add `scale = 1` to your `geom_density_ridges` call then the plots will just touch (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggridges/vignettes/introduction.html)). You can also have scale values less than 1 to increase separation.

Comment: That's not what I want. I need the actual histograms to be stacked in each plot as in the second example. Changing `scale` only changes the vertical distance between the plots, but each plot remains unchanged.

Comment: Oh sorry the wording was kind confusing. Usually that would be `position = "stack"` but I don't think that works with `geom_density_ridges`. If your issue is aesthetics I would try different themes

Answer (score 0):

it sounds trivial, but I
tried exchanging

```
position = position_stack()
```

with

```
position = "stack"
```

in your dplyr code, and it worked.

Is this what you wanted?

Comment: It does not work for me... Did you add this to the ggridges example?